# Legacy back to uefi please asap help

Tags: uefi, bios, grub-legacy

Recently, I forgot my bios supervisor password. I installed Ubuntu in legacy.
Now if I go to my bios using unlock password provided by
biosbug.com
But all the options are greyed out. I can only select date,time, user password that's it
All other options are greyed
How shud i go back to uefi?
Should I install Ubuntu again after changing to Ubuntu?
Please help me, I am new to all this
Ps: I don't have windows. I removed it. I have only Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: But is UEFI boot os disabled in BIOS, you can't turn it back on without knowing the password.

Comment: @Nmath You don't have to reinstall to switch from legacy to uefi. But I am afraid the problem is different.

Comment: Why would you need to switch to UEFI? It doesn't matter much.

Comment: The boot is slow and there are more bugs

Comment: My laptop was uefi when it was windows. I want it back

Comment: Ubuntu is lagging a lot . I used ubuntu in uefi too. It was way less laggy

Comment: How to reset the whole bios or something . Plz help me with any other way

Comment: UEFI won't fix any lagging. Ask a question about the real problem. Resetting your BIOS is not related to Ubuntu.

Comment: So do you recommend not to go back to uefi? Is legacy fine